# Getting results from addOnSuccessListener

Tags: java, android, google-mlkit

I'm hoping to implement a simple object detection app on android using a custom model I've already trained, and I'm following this [custom model ML Kit tutorial](https://developers.google.com/ml-kit/vision/object-detection/custom-models/android#java_10) as a guide.

According to the command prompt in Android Studios, it has successfully generated the bounding boxes and such but I don't have any idea on how to access the data inside the addOnSuccessListener.

```js
objectDetector.process(image).addOnFailureListener(e -> {
            errorMessage.set(e.getMessage());
        }).addOnSuccessListener(results -> {
            for (DetectedObject detectedObject : results) {
                Rect boundingBox = detectedObject.getBoundingBox();
                Integer trackingId = detectedObject.getTrackingId();
                for (DetectedObject.Label label : detectedObject.getLabels()) {
                    String text = label.getText();
                    int index = label.getIndex();
                    float confidence = label.getConfidence();
                }
            }
        });
```

Are there any good tutorials online that'll help me with this problem?  Or sample codes similar to this that I could study?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Store the required values in global variables that you can access from anywhere:

e.g. Within your activity:

```
Rect boundingBox;
Integer trackingId;
...
```

then inside of the result callback:

```
results -> {
    for (DetectedObject detectedObject : results) {
        boundingBox = detectedObject.getBoundingBox();
        trackingId = detectedObject.getTrackingId();
        ...
    }
}
```

Now you can use these values anywhere. Make sure you're checking for nullity if you think that the variables are never initialised because you never get the results back in the first place.

Also, it seems that you may be having multiple objects, so you can create a list of objects to hold all the references:

```
ArrayList<Rect> boundingBoxes;
...
```

and then:

```
for (DetectedObject detectedObject : results) {
    boundingBoxes.add(detectedObject.getBoundingBox());              
}
```

now all the returned boxes are in the above list and you can iterate through it and use it accordingly.

More efficiently, you can collect all the returned objects in a list and only parse the parameters as you need them.

```
ArrayList<DetectedObject> detectedObjects;
```

Answer (score 0):

The sample code you posted already provide an example for accessing the data in the OnSuccessListener directly.  If you want to draw the bounding box out or printing how many objects are detected.., we can do there.
However, if you want to store and access those data later, you can store it as Nikos mentioned.